rewriting R6 to S4 class in R
I have this function here
person1$check_infection(person2)

person1 and person2 are R6 class objects, I have already rewritten the check_infection method in S4, how do I write the above function in S4? I have already tried:
check_infection(person1, person2)

But it is not working as the function in R6 class. I had created the check_infection generic as follows;
setGeneric('check_infection',
           \(.Object, other) {
             standardGeneric('check_infection')
           })

setMethod('check_infection',
          signature = 'Person',
          \(.Object, other) {
            if (.Object@S & other@I & runif(1) < beta / (N * contact_rate) * dt) {
              .Object <- Infect(.Object)
            }
         return(.Object)
          }
)




What did you write for the check_infection method in S4?  Did you create a check_infection generic?  Show us your code.

Yes I did create a generic for check_infection
